# How to send multiple data of ports through UART?

Tags: c, microcontroller, pic, uart

I've changed the code for the receiver but the transmitter is pretty much the same, so in the receiver I've canceled the Interrupt and instead I read the data in a loop where I check every time for the state of the `RC2IF_bit` and the check is made by the same order the transmitter sends the data to make sure which port is sending data.
The problem is in simulation on proteus when I receive the data and output it on leds they work fine and the data is sent right but in the middle of the simulation when I watch it I found that they change states for a glance, for example if i send `PORTA = 0X2D`  I receive the same value and the right leds turn-on but for a second they turn-off then they turn-on again, is this a problem in the code written.

```
 /*This is the transmitter code*/
void UART2_TX_init ();      //UART2 transmission initialization function porototype
void SEND_data (int output);     //Send data function prototype


void main()
{
     ANSELA = 0X00;        //Disable analogue function on PORTA
     ANSELE = 0X00;        //Disable analogue function on PORTE
     ANSELF = 0X00;        //Disable analogue function on PORTF
     TRISA = 0XFF;         // SET PORTA AS INPUT (AUTOMATIC BUTTONS)
     TRISB = 0XFF;         //SET PORTB AS INPUT (OFF BUTTONS)
     TRISD = 0XFF;         //SET PORTD AS INPUT (MANUAL BUTTONS)
     TRISE = 0XFF;         //SET PORTE AS INPUT (HIGH BUTTONS)
     TRISF = 0XFF;         //SET PORTF AS INPUT (LOW BUTTONS)
     TRISC = 0XFF;         //SET PORTC AS INPUT (TRIP BUTTONS)
     TRISG0_bit = 0;    //set PORTC pin0 as output for MAX487 DE pin
     PORTG.F0= 1;      //set PORTC pin0 HIGH , set    MAX487 as transmitter.
     UART2_TX_init();      //call UART1 transmission initialization

     while (1)
     {
                SEND_data(PORTA);   //send data of automatic
                delay_ms(10);
               SEND_data(PORTB);    //send data of off
               delay_ms(10);
               SEND_data(PORTD);    //send daata of manual
               delay_ms(10);
               SEND_data(PORTE);   //send data of high
               delay_ms(10);
               SEND_data(PORTF);   //send data of low
               delay_ms(10);
               SEND_data(PORTC);   //send data of TRIP
               delay_ms(10);
    }
}

 /*This function takes the data needed to be send
   as an integer. Wait for the TSR to be empty and
   start the transmission*/

void SEND_data (int output)
{
         while (!TRMT_TX2STA_bit){};    //checks if TSR is empty or not if empty TRMT_BIT is set and write to transmit register
         TX2REG = output;        //write data to be send in the transmission register

}




/*This function initializes the UART2 as an asynchronous
 transmitter at a baud rate of 9600kbps*/

void UART2_TX_init ()
{
    BAUD2CON = 0X08;
    BRGH_TX2STA_bit = 1;
    SP2BRGL = 207;
    SYNC_TX2STA_bit = 0X00;
    SPEN_RC2STA_bit = 0X01;
    TRISG1_bit = 0X01;
    TRISG2_bit = 0X01;
    TXEN_TX2STA_bit = 0X01;

}




/*This is the receiver code*/
void UART2_RX_init ();   // Receiver initialization function prototype
void main()
{

     ANSELA = 0X00;       // Disable analog function on PORTA
     ANSELE = 0X00;       // Disable analog function on PORTE
     ANSELF = 0X00;       // Disable analog function on PORTF
     TRISA = 0X00;        //set PORTA as output
     TRISB = 0X00;        //set PORTB as output
     TRISD = 0X00;        //set PORTD as output
     TRISE = 0X00;        //set PORTE as output
     TRISF = 0X00;        //set PORTF as output
     TRISC = 0X00;        //set PORTF as output
     PORTA = 0x00;        //clear PORTA
     PORTB = 0x00;        //clear PORTB
     PORTD = 0x00;        //clear PORTD
     PORTE = 0x00;        //clear PORTE
     PORTF = 0x00;        //clear PORTF
     PORTC = 0x00;        //clear PORTC
     TRISG0_bit = 0x00;   //set PORTC pin0 as output for MAX487 RE pin
     PORTG.F0 = 0x00;     // set PORTC pin0 as LOW , set MAX487 as receiver
     UART2_RX_init();     //call receiver initialization function
     while (1)
     {
             while (!RC2IF_bit) ;      //check if the RCIF flag is up to tell if there is a new data
             PORTA =~ RC2REG;          //write the new data to the specified port
             while (!RC2IF_bit) ;
             PORTB =~ RC2REG;
             while (!RC2IF_bit) ;
             PORTD =~ RC2REG;
             while (!RC2IF_bit) ;
             PORTE =~ RC2REG;
             while (!RC2IF_bit) ;
             PORTF =~ RC2REG;
             while (!RC2IF_bit) ;
             PORTC =~ RC2REG;
     }


}
/*This function initializes UART2 as an asynchronous
  receiver at a baud rate of 9600kbps with continous
  reception NO INTERRUPT ON RECEIVE*/
void UART2_RX_init ()
{
    BAUD2CON = 0X08;
    BRGH_TX2STA_bit = 1;
    SP2BRGL = 207;
    SYNC_TX2STA_bit = 0X00;
    SPEN_RC2STA_bit = 0X01;
    TRISG1_bit = 0X01;
    TRISG2_bit = 0X01;
    CREN_RC2STA_bit = 0X01;
}
```

Comment: Please add more details to your question what happens and what you would want to happen. "the output being received on the other PIC seems to flash and not stable" is not clear to me. Just a few thoughts without knowing the specific controller: The behavior of `interrupt` may depend on timing. What means `if (RCIF_bit ==1)`? Exactly / at least one byte available in receive buffer? Assuming `RCREG` reads last received byte. Is there a FIFO? What if there is no new data yet? Maybe in `interrupt` you should read 1 byte only and use a static counter to decide which of `PORTA..F` to send this byte.

Comment: the whole idea is that I want to read the input from some switches, each port has five switches on it, then send this data by UART to another PIC in which it turns on the corresponding bit for the corresponding port. The program works fine when i transmit data for any three ports but when i add another port the leds on the receiver  keeps flashing and the data being transmitted is not received correctly.

Comment: never never never put a delay in your receive interrupt. the interrupt routine should be as short as possible.

Comment: @aymanmagdy You should [edit] your question to add more information instead of answering in comments. My questions are also intended as hints what you should think about. As others already wrote in the answers your protocol needs synchronization. Your receiver implementation may read the same data more than once which will lead to data being written to the wrong port.

Answer (score 2):

First of all I want to say a few words about protocol design. Any communication protocol, if you want it to be reliable, should implement at least two things: frame synchronization and error checking. Okay, there are some specialized protocols that don't use frames and represent data as a continuous stream, but it's definitely not your case. So if you don't want to mess around with weird bugs, I highly recommend you to implement these things.

Now about your code. It looks like `GET_data` waits for the transmit register to be empty and writes to it one byte. I don't see anything wrong with that. But your receiver looks suspicious. You wait for the `RCIF` flag to be set and then read 5 times from the input register `RCREG`. But non-zero `RCIF` means that you received **one** byte. You can't wait for `RCIF` once and then read from `RCREG` multiple times. You should wait for `RCIF` before **every** read from `RCREG`.

I would be happy to give you an example of the working code, but I can't come up with a simple solution that will fit your current architecture.
I can give you example how to do it in a right way, but it will look totally different.

Comment: i would appreciate any examples that can guide me.

Comment: @aymanmagdy Do you use OS or you want a bare metal solution? Does your program need to do something else besides reading and writing ports?

Comment: No I just want to read the value of a port send it read it on the receiver and so on for the other ports.

Answer (score 1):

Some things:

- the UART receive ISR should be as short as possible and just write the data into a buffer and contain absolutly not any delay routines.
- use one interupt for every received byte.
- start your frame with a startbyte. e.g `'S'`
- end your frame with a checksum byte.
- do the portwrite in your mainloop after you detect a complete frame in your buffer (startbyte + databytes + correct chechsum)